# Accesing a javascript object defined in a subnamespace and the js file being imported into the HTML

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

how to access  an object in the namespace.
1) i have  a html which imports script files

one script defines the namesapce app and the other script attaches a object to it

how do i access the object and start using it

### app.js

```
var app = (function(jQuery){
    if (!jQuery) {
        alert(app.resources["MISSING_LIB"]);
        return null;
    }

    return {
        init: function() {
            //code for init the app related variables and subnamspaces
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    app.init();
});
```

---

personal.js

```
function(app){
    if (app) {
        app.Cache = function(nativeStorage,serializer ) {
            this.storage = nativeStorage;
            this.serializer = serializer;
        }

        app.Cache.prototype = {
            setItem: function( key, value ){
                this.storage.setItem(key, this.serializer.stringify( value ));
                return( this );
            }
        };

        var personalcontentstorage = new app.Cache(localStorage,JSON);
    } else {
        alert("app is undefined!");
    }
})(app);
```

---

### myhtml.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="${ '/js/app.js'" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${ '/js/personal.js'" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>
        Exploring HTML5's localStorage
    </h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            personalcontentstorage.setItem("mykey","myValue") ;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to  access the  object  "personalcontentstorage" so that i can use its methods .I get a undefined error when accesing hte object.I  cannot access the object the way i have written above

Comment: `init: function() {` in your app.js definition is a syntax error. check your console.

Comment: The code i have put here for consideration is pseudo code, My original app.js is a huge file and it is working fine. I want the approach to  use the object defined in personal.js to be used in the html's dom ready

Comment: Thanks all for the feed back , being a  java developer trying to undserstand oops of JS in a fast paced project , your feedback really helped me  get my concepts of JS right :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `app.js`, the `app` variable is not what you think:

```
var app = (function(jQuery){
    // function body
})(jQuery);
```

What is being assigned to `app` is the return value from the self-executing anonymous function after the equal sign. Which is undefined (or `null`, in case jQuery is falsey). You have to have the function return something to be assigned to the `app` var.

Comment: You just edited the question to add a return value, so I'm not sure this answer applies anymore. I'm also not sure if the return value was on the original code in the first place, or if you only added it after my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can't just reference a variable declared in another scope like that. That's why scope exists. If you want to grab the `personalcontentstorage` variable, just return it:

```
// assign your IIFE to a variable
var something = (function(app){
    if (app) {
        // snip
        return new app.Cache(localStorage,JSON);
    } else {
        alert("app is undefined!");
    }
})(app);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // use the variable your IIFE's return was stored in
    something.setItem("mykey","myValue") ;
});
```

Comment: Thank you  very much for the solution/advice , it solved my problem. From the starting i knew that it was a scope related issue. was learning  JS on the job and i   got really confused. this would definetely add to my experience

Answer (score 0):

How about returning it from your personal.js function?

```
var Personal = (function(app) {
    if (app) {
        app.Cache = function(nativeStorage, serializer) {
            this.storage = nativeStorage;
            this.serializer = serializer;
        }

        app.Cache.prototype = {
            setItem: function(key, value) {
                this.storage.setItem(key, this.serializer.stringify(value));
                return (this);
            }
        };

        var personalcontentstorage = new app.Cache(localStorage, JSON);
    } else {
        alert("app is undefined!");
    }

    return {
        storage: personalcontentstorage
    };
}(app));
```

Then in your HTML file, you'd just reference:

```
Personal.storage.setItem("myKey", "myValue");
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for. Your code is very hard to read and by your own admission it's not really your code, just something sort of like it. Please try to post your questions with well-structured, somewhat functional code. :-)​

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable within a function, that variable isn't visible outside of the function, e.g.

```
(function () {
    var foo;
}());

// foo is not visible here
```

The only variables that are visible everywhere are *global variables* (or more precisely, properties of the global object, which in a browser's case is `window`). These can be defined in three ways:

1. Use `var`, but not inside a function:

   ```
   var foo;

   (function () {
       // foo is visible here
   }());

   // foo is also visible here
   ```
2. Explicitly attach your variable to the `window` object:

   ```
   (function () {
       window.foo = 7;
   }());

   // foo is visible here
   ```
3. Don't use `var` the first time you assign something to the variable. This is definitely the wrong way to do things: it's not obvious to someone reading the code that you intended to create a global variable.

Global variables have various risks and drawbacks. If you include third party scripts in your page they might use the same global variable names and interfere with your own scripts. It's generally best to keep the number of global variables you use to an absolute minimum.

I often use this pattern, creating a single global variable to contain all of the code for a project (you can replace `MySite` with the name of the project):

```
// Create a global variable that can contain everything else
window.MySite = {};

// Add something to the namespace
MySite.foo = (function () {
    // Code that isn't visible globally here

    return someValueForFoo;
}());

// Elsewhere in my code I can easily access `someValueForFoo`:
MySite.foo
```

Applying this to your project:

```
window.MySite = {};

// In app.js
MySite.App = (function (jQuery) {
    // ...
}(jQuery));

// In personal.js
MySite.storage = (function (jQuery) {
    // ...
    return new MySite.App.Cache(localStorage,JSON);
}(jQuery));

// Elsewhere in your code
MySite.storage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```